# how to find the coordinates of a point?

Tags: vectors

I wish you can help me I have a quiz tomorrow, even by just explain to me the method, I have  points $A(1.5,-2)$ and $B(-1, 3.5)$ and vector $\vec{u}(-2,1)$.

How can we find the coordinates of the points $M$ and $N$ if we are given $3 \vec{MA} = 2 \vec{MB}$ and  $\vec{BN} = \vec{u}$?

Comment: Downvotes with no comment for suggested improvement.  *Nice!*

Comment: I edited your question to improve formatting.  Please review the updated question and let me know if I made any incorrect edits as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: Let $M = (x,y) \Rightarrow 3\vec{MA} = 2\vec{MB} \Rightarrow 3(x-1.5,y-(-2)) = 2(x-(-1),y-3.5)$, and $N = (a,b) \Rightarrow \vec{BN} = \vec{u} \Rightarrow (a-(-1),b-3.5) = (-2,1)$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write the coordinates of M as $(x,y)$, and express the vectors MA and MB in terms of $x$ and $y$. You should end up with two simultaneous equations.